# Android notification action on api 16

Tags: android

According to the documentation here: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.1.html#Connectivity, notification action is available since api 16. However when I am testing this api on android api 16 (Not using notification compat library of course), I receive this error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.app.Notification$Action
```

Then I checked the AOSP source code: http://androidxref.com/4.1.1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/Notification.java#443

As you can see from the source code, the class Notification.Action is marked @hide so it isn't exposed in sdk. So what's going on here? Is it an error in android documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an error in the documentation, insofar as they link to the wrong version of the `addAction()` method. The one that you can use starting on API Level 16 is [this one](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#addAction(int,%20java.lang.CharSequence,%20android.app.PendingIntent)).